# Chrome and Safari not honorring HPKP

Tags: google-chrome, security, http-headers, hsts

I added HPKP header to my site, but it is not honored by Chrome or Safari. I tested it manually by setting a proxy and by going to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and looking for my domain - which did not found. The HPKP seems correct, and I also tested it using [HPKP toolset](https://report-uri.io/home/pkp_analyse) so I know it is valid.

I am thinking I might be doing something weird with my flow. I have a web app, which is served over `myapp.example.com`. On login, the app redirects the user to `authserver.example.com/begin` to initiate OpenID Connect Authorization Code flow. HPKP header is returned only from `authserver.example.com/begin`, and I think this might be the issue. I have `include-subdomain` in the HPKP header so I think this is not the issue.

This is the HPKP header (line breaks added for readability):

```
public-key-pins:max-age=864000;includeSubDomains; \
pin-sha256="bcppaSjDk7AM8C/13vyGOR+EJHDYzv9/liatMm4fLdE="; \
pin-sha256="cJjqBxF88mhfexjIArmQxvZFqWQa45p40n05C6X/rNI="; \
report-uri="https://reporturl.example"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Its not limited to Chrome and Safari. All modern browsers do it; and many web components do it because its a *"feature"* of the web security model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added HPKP header to my site, but it is not honored by Chrome or Safari...  I tested it manually by setting a proxy...

[RFC 7469, Public Key Pinning Extension for HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7469), kind of sneaks that past you. The IETF published it with overrides, so an attacker can break a known good pinset. Its mentioned once in the standard by name ***"override"*** but the details are not provided. The IETF also failed to publish a discussion in a security considerations section.

More to the point, the proxy you set engaged the override. It does not matter if its the wrong proxy, a proxy certificate installed by an mobile device OEM, or a proxy controlled by an attacker who tricked a user to install it. The web security model and the standard allow it. They embrace interception and consider it a valid use case.

Something else they did was make the reporting of the broken pinset a *Must Not* or *Should Not*. It means the user agent is complicit in the coverup, too. That's not discussed in a security considerations section, either. They really don't want folks to know their supposed secure connection is being intercepted.

Your best bet to avoid it is move outside the web security model. Don't use browser based apps when security is a concern. Use a hybrid app and perform the pinning yourself. Your hybrid app can host a WebView Control or View, but still get access to the channel to verify parameters. Also see [OWASP's Certificate and Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning).

Also see [Comments on draft-ietf-websec-key-pinning](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/websec/current/msg02280.html) on the IETF mailing list. One of the suggestions in the comment was change the title to *"Public Key Pinning Extension for HTTP with Overrides"* to highlight the feature. Not surprisingly, that's not something they want. They are trying to do it surreptitiously without user knowledge.

---

Here's the relevant text from RFC 6479:

> 2.7.  Interactions with Preloaded Pin Lists
>
> UAs MAY choose to implement additional sources of pinning
> information, such as through built-in lists of pinning information.
> Such UAs should allow users to override such additional sources,
> including disabling them from consideration.
>
> The effective policy for a Known Pinned Host that has both built-in
> Pins and Pins from previously observed PKP header response fields is
> implementation-defined.

Comment: Thank you for the details answer! I left a comment on the answer below, but as your answer it pretty similar I guess it is relevant also to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Locally installed CAs (like those used for proxies like you say are running) override any HPKP checks.

This is necessary so as not to completely break the internet given the prevalence of them: anti-virus software and proxies used in large corporations basically MITM https traffic through a locally issued certificate as otherwise they could not read the traffic.

Some argue that locally installing a CA requires access to your machine, and at that point it's game over anyway, but to me this still massively reduces the protection of HPKP and that, coupled with the high risks of using HPKP, means I am really not a fan of it.

Comment: So what is the point in HPKP? Maybe I am missing something... Also, why I could not see the settings in `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`? If you are saying is true, I would expect to see it there, although it is override by the local proxy...

Comment: HPKP is only useful for non-proxied traffic. As I stated that, to me, is a big (but necessary so as to avoid breaking lots of users) hole as it means it doesn't protect against attacks like Superfish. Yes I take on board that once the local PC is compromised then there is little you can do, but still seems like a big hole. And that, plus given the dangers that HPKP can so (due to site owners committing suicide) mean I really don't think it's worth the effort.

Comment: The policy is only stored in `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` if the policy has been validated. This is to prevent a non-valid policy being stored and breaking a site. If you only visited via the proxy, then the HPKP policy was never valid (as none of the pins were used for that connection) so the policy is ignored. If you visit it without the proxy, it should be stored and available on that page. Note also that two completely independent pins must be used for a valid policy so if you are only pinning the root CA cert and your leaf cert, and both are used in same chain then this will not work.

Comment: What I did was visiting it once without the proxy and then once with the proxy, so it should be validated. I also used 2 different pins (production and backup). But I think I am going to remove the HPKP as I do not see the point of using it anyway...

Comment: Agree it should have validated then. Can really tell why it didn't without seeing the real site and certs you have for that.

Comment: I found out why it was not shown in `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`: I checked for `example.com` and not for `authserver.example.com`. An embarrassing mistake...

Comment: Cool. Good to know it works like I thought it did :-)